# how to present a menu or a dialog with items on arrival of a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

we know that we can customize our notification on the status bar by adding icons, change font, truen the LED on or add some styles. but is it possible in android to show a menu with some items once the notification arrived?

Comment: You mean a dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html):

> **An action allows users to go directly from the notification to an
>   Activity in your application, where they can look at one or more
>   events or do further work.**
>
> A notification can provide multiple actions. You should always define
>   the action that's triggered when the user clicks the notification;
>   usually this action opens an Activity in your application. You can
>   also add buttons to the notification that perform additional actions
>   such as snoozing an alarm or responding immediately to a text message;
>   this feature is available as of Android 4.1. If you use additional
>   action buttons, you must also make their functionality available in an
>   Activity in your app

That's how notification should perform additional actions. If you're going to *"present a menu or a dialog with items on arrival of a notification"* - that's **totally wrong behaviour**.